# AOT giving errors like module not found?

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I am trying to use AOT in my project. I have created a tsconfig-aot.json file as follows

```
   {
"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "",
"declaration": false,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"lib": [
  "es2016",
  "dom"
],
"mapRoot": "./",
"module": "es2015",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
"sourceMap": true,
"target": "es5",
"typeRoots": [
  "../node_modules/@types"
]
},"files": [
"src/app/app.module.ts",
"src/main.ts",
"src/app/shared/shared.module.ts"
],
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
 "genDir": "aot",
"skipMetadataEmit" : true
 }
}
```

I have so many components and modules like shared.module.ts, vendor.module.ts ... etc

when i use command

```
  node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json
```

i am getting so many errors similar to

```
Error at D:/Projects/myproject/index/public/www/src/app/shared/sidebar/sidebar.ts:6:12: Cannot find name 'module'.
```

Error at D:/Projects/myproject/index/public/www/src/app/shared/sidebar/topnav.ts:6:12: Cannot find name 'module'.

what ia m doing wrong? how can i fix this?

Comment: are you using module.Id

Comment: yes my topnav component is like @Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'top-nav',
    templateUrl: 'topnav.html'
})